# How can I add a facebook user login functionality

Tags: python, django, facebook, user-registration

My python version is 3.4.3 and my django version is 1.9.6 . I tried many django facebook registrations apps  but almost all the versions are outdated.

What I want is to allow users to login via facebook and check if their friends are registered to my website. Your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package for Django third party auth that is well maintained, Django-allauth:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-allauth/

I use it for Facebook, Twitter and Google auth methods.

There is also a good step by step tutorial:

http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

The tutorial walks through Facebook as an example. It is slightly out of date but still works. Facebook has tweaked their interface since it was written. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to develop a Web-Application and use FaceBook login, register as a facebook developer (it is free) and then go through their instructions. It is completely self-explanatory and quite easy to follow.

Visit : developers.facebook.com for clear way of how to do this.

Comment: Well, I don't know javascript. Can you share something else so that I could easily do it in Python?

Comment: http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Try this link. It links Python based apps with Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/facebook-authentication/

you can choose from this list of django packages available, based on your requirement. If you are planning to integrate other social site logins in future then go with `django-allauth` or `django-social-auth`.